# Approximation for confluent hypergeometric function 1F1(-aX,-X,-1)

Tags: power-series, approximation, hypergeometric-function

This question concerns Kummers confluent Hypergeometric function $_1F_1$, sometimes denoted $M$.  Recall that
$$
M(a;b;z) = {_1F_1 (a;b;z)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{(a)_n}{(b)_n}
$$

I am seeking to approximate $M(-\lfloor \alpha X\rfloor;-X;-1)$ when $X$ is a large positive real and $\alpha \in [0,1]$, perhaps by way of a series in $\alpha$.

Numerically, I find that:

$$
M(-\lfloor \alpha X\rfloor;-X;-1) \approx 1 - \left( \frac{e-1}{e}+\frac{\pi}{10}\right)\alpha + \left( \frac{\pi}{10}\right) \alpha^2
$$
is within 0.4% of the true value when $X\gg100$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$.  However, I see no combinatorial interpretation, or way to derive this from the hypergeometric series, or general approximation to higher orders.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$${_1\hspace{-1.5px}F_1}(-\lfloor\alpha X\rfloor;-X;-1)=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-\lfloor\alpha X\rfloor)_k}{(-X)_k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=
\\\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
\frac{(\lfloor\alpha X\rfloor)!\,(X-k)!}{X!\,(\lfloor\alpha X\rfloor-k)!}
\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$
and
$$\lim_{X \to \infty}
\frac{(\alpha X-\{\alpha X\})!\,(X-k)!}{X!\,(\alpha X-\{\alpha X\}-k)!}=
\alpha^k,$$
taking the element-wise limit gives
$$\lim_{X \to \infty}
 {_1\hspace{-1.5px}F_1}(-\lfloor\alpha X\rfloor;-X;-1)=e^{-\alpha}.$$